# 3 D game development in Scene kit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am designing a app using Scene kit in which i want to handle Camera controls like 3 D games.
How to Develop 3 D game in Scene kit? Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is _very_ broad, but "yes" it is possible

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to help you with specific issues and advice. But yes, you can develop 3D games in Scene Kit.

Comment: Please mark an answer as "Accepted" if it provides a satisfactory answer to your question. This helps keep SO nice and tidy :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following examples (both are based on SceneKit):

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Bananas/Introduction/Intro.html
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Introduction/Intro.html

They are pretty good starting  points.

Comment: It would be nice if someone actually posted good tutorials.. especially using the scn files.